# Mocking AngularJS XHR requests for testing using Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest, jasmine

Ok, I am pretty sure this is really weird behaviour - and I have no idea what is going on...

Code below.

I am running a Jasmine spec on possibly the most simple AngularJS controller ever, which makes a call to a function (getSuppliers) upon initialisation, which in turn makes a http get request, which I have mocked out using $httpBackend. The weirdness happens when I actually run the test. It fails with `Expected undefined to equal 'list of suppliers'`.

So I stuck in some `debugger;`s (1 and 2) and ran the spec in Chrome. This is the weird part. Debugger 2 gets hit before Debugger 1, meaning that the getSuppliers function returns with the value of `undefined` before the mock even has a chance to do it's magic. For the record, when I continue on and let debugger 1 come up as well, data has the correct value of `"list of suppliers"`, so if I could just get the mock to run in the right place i should be sweet. Anyone have any idea what the hell is going on here?

spec.js

```
describe("Supplier Controller", function(){
    ctrl = null;
    scope = null;
    httpBackend = null;
    supplierController = null;

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller,$rootScope,$httpBackend) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller;
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;

        httpBackend.expectGET('/suppliers.json').respond("list of suppliers");
        supplierController = ctrl('supplierCtrl', { $scope: scope});
        $httpBackend.flush();
    }));

    it("gets a list of suppliers", function(){
        expect(scope.suppliers).toEqual( "list of suppliers" );
    });
});
```

supplier.js

```
function supplierCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.suppliers = getSuppliers($http);
}

function getSuppliers($http){
    var suppliers;
    $http.get('/suppliers.json').success(function(data) {
        debugger; // Debugger 1
        suppliers = data;
    }).error(function(){ suppliers = "something else"; } );
    debugger; // Debugger 2
    return suppliers;
};
```

Thanks for any wisdom...

Comment: debugger 2 is probably hit before debugger 1 because $http returns a promise. That means the script isn't blocked by the success callback, but continues execution.

Comment: I think you're probably right. By setting the value of `$scope.suppliers` directly inside the http get request (ie. `$scope.suppliers = data;` do not get any strange behaviour.